# sshd fails to login user

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd, pam

I could not ssh into one of my servers this morning after successfully doing so most recently yesterday.

```
ssh hostname
Connection closed by hostname port 22
```

I rebooted system and it did not fix the issue.

I dug out a keyboard and a display and could not find any issues or messages in /var/log/messages /var/log/warn or journalctl.

I stopped sshd (systemctl stop sshd), ran sshd from the command line (sshd -ddd) and there are no error messages, and no connection.  sshd does unexpectedly terminate with an exit value 255.  Note that when running as a system daemon it is not exiting, just not reporting anything.

Another symptom is that ssh does not prompt for a password for either a non-existing user or an existing user.  sshd will however log that the non-existing user is invalid:

```
Invalid user bob from [host] port 40718
```

While investigating this issue, I found that usermod fails.

```
usermod -a -G nogroup nobody
usermod: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Thinking this is a symptom of my sshd failure I started to investigate usermod failing and found the deep pit of despair that is PAM.
This question [Switch on PAM debugging to Syslog](https://serverfault.com/questions/249671/switch-on-pam-debugging-to-syslog) documents the zero ability to debug anything within PAM without recompling from source.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is a result of a incomplete patch or patch dependency that got installed yesterday.
Resolved by installing patches.